# Is this formula for calculating the ways to arrange the 5 digits correct? If it is, why?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to solve how many ways are these to arrange 6,7,8,9,9, these 5 digits. 
I asked my friend, he told me that I can use $\frac{5!}{2!}$ to do this. I have no idea how this work, could you guys please explain to me? 
I knew that we could have 5! way to manipulating these digits, my problem is how do we know there would be 2! repeated.

Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: @hgs Sorry, I just changed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we had $6,7,8,9,\color{red} 9$

Now it is easier, because we can differentiate the 9's

There are $5!$ ways to arrange $5$ objects.

And for each of these arrangements we can swap the 9's and a colorblind person would know the difference.

$\frac {5!}{2}$

Comment: Oh my god, You make it really easy for me. I really want to thank you, sir, my respect. But why do we need to divide it, instead to minus it.

Comment: Half the arrangements have the red 9 first, half have the black 9 first.

Comment: Sir, first time in my life, someone explains this so clearly to me. My respect. Thank you

Comment: @Dough M Actually i ended up focus on your last sentence. What does that mean

Comment: Yes, sir, you have a typo, forgetting the factorial sign. @Doug M

Comment: @HenryCai There is no mistake.  Note that $2! = 2$.

Comment: Thank you. I see.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the rule of product

- Pick where in the resulting permutation the $6$ goes  (*five options*)
- Pick where in the resulting permutation the $7$ goes (*four remaining options*)
- Pick where in the resulting permutation the $8$ goes (*three remaining options*)
- Let the final positions remaining be occupied by both $9$'s

This gives a total of $5\times 4\times 3$ (*which is clearly equal to $\frac{5!}{2!}$*)

---

Even more generally, you might choose to use [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) for larger problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, tbh, I would take a look at the link. I would like to know the mechanism behind the formula

Answer (score 1):

In total, there are 5! ways of ordering 5 objects in a row. Since two of the digits are the same $9,9$, each number we get appears exactly 2! times (second time when the first 9 and the second 9 flip places).

That's why you get $5!/2!$.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is how do we know there are n! times repeated, where n is the repeated digit.